# How to make child object a member of two parents in unity?

Tags: unity, heirarchy

So I have an parent game object that has multiple objects.

This format is desirable:

```
-GameObject
    -object1 (abstract)
        -subobject1

    -object2 (abstract)
        -subobject2

    -object3 (abstract)
        -subobject1
        -subobject2
// There are two objects in the scene, subobject1 and subobject2
```

The problem is when i drag and drop one subobject from an object it removes it from the other object. When i copy the subobjects to another object, there are now two.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Each transform in Unity has one and only one parent, as is typical for hierarchies and tree data structures. It can have grandparents and great grandparents though. What is the player-visible outcome you hope to achieve by multiple parenting? We might be able to achieve that outcome in a different way.

Comment: It's a rubiks cube. So the game object is the whole cube. Objects are slices and subobjects are the individual cubes.

Comment: Great. Now edit your question to ask about that desired outcome. The answer to "How to make child object a member of two parents" is "You cannot" — not super useful. But the answers to "How can I rotate slices of a Rubik's Cube" will actually solve your root problem. In general, asking about your problem/application gets you to useful answers faster than asking about one conceived solution.

Comment: Nice to know that you can't. Thank you. Not sure why you're annoyed... I thought this was a clear and concise question. Which is the whole goal of a question. Guess I'll find another way to do it...

Comment: I'm not annoyed, just giving you advice on how to reframe your question to get answers that are more useful to you, faster - [avoiding a common Q&A issue we call the X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You can edit your question and get working alternatives right away.

Comment: I'm not sure if you imposed a question ban on my account, if you didn't, disregard what i'm about to say, i'd admit there are questions i do need to fix.

If you did. I believe this to be unjustified and quite frankly a little arrogant. Having questions that lead to a clear and concise answer is what i strive for when looking for answers myself. If the answer is as simple as no you can't. That is fine, it will help those who have the same question. It doesn't need to go further.

Comment: No, I did not impose a question ban on you. If you recognize that what you're about to say is not grounded in any particular evidence, it may be better not to make the accusation at all. All I did was offer guidance for how to improve this question with constructive edits, which you chose to disregard. You'll have a much better time on this site if you practice viewing other contributors as collaborators and not as potential enemies.

Comment: @Snuffles Questions bans are imposed by the system, mods have no way to impose them or lift them, and they don't even know the exact rules that govern them; they are also specific to each site. If you have a question ban on StackOverflow, you need to fix your questions there; and we don't know about it here. Your account here does not seem to be in a position where you'll get a question ban soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The object scene graph is a tree. Each object can have exactly one parent.

But what you can do is reference the same game object from multiple MonoBehaviours.

When a script has a `public GameObject something`, then multiple instances of that script can reference the same object.

If you want to simulate a rubic's cube, then you could do that by making both the 9 slices and the 26 cubes direct children of the cube game object. The script of the slices would then have a `public GameObject[] cubes` referencing the cubes which are currently part of that slice. The initial assignment of cubes to slices can be done in the inspector. After rotating a slice, you would have the script look at the four other slices which are also affected by that rotation and change which cubes are now part of which slice.